# "Paper never refused ink" - has any one heard a more modern/online version?

Tags: idioms

I'd imagine most of us have heard of the phrase "paper never refused ink", roughly meaning "they'll" print anything.

Can anybody think of a more modern/online version?

Comment: Screens never refused pixels. (?)

Comment: “They'll print anything these days.” (Quoted rather whimsically by Bond in 'Tomorrow Never Dies', 1997.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Phrase  Finder has a suggestion:

[Paper never refused ink:](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/39/messages/672.html)

> - The phrase does emphasise the importance of retaining a healthy scepticism towards what is written in the paper/ magazine/ report/ memo etc.
>     But it also means that one may write whatever one will, however fallacious, absurd, obscene, incendiary, murderous, and so on. The paper can never resist what the writer wishes to pen on to it.
> - **An updated version of this saying is that just as paper does not refuse ink, nor do computers reject keystrokes.**

Answer (score -1):

Words are cheap, deeds have a higher price.

Comment: Would you please add a source for this quote?

Comment: Also show explicitly how this answers the question (see the other answer).