# A modern equivalent for "at the coalface"

Tags: british-english, idiom-requests

> I let you believe that I am one of the nation's top geneticists, when actually I am a moderately successful scientist who is now coasting on past research, doing the odd bit of examining or consultancy. I haven't been **at the coalface** for years.
> <sub>From the novel, *Apple Tree Yard*. By Louise Doughty</sub>

The Free Dictionary defines the British and Australian idiom [at the coalface](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+the+coalface) as: *someone who is at the coalface is doing the work involved in a job, not talking about it, planning it, or controlling it.*

[The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/32/messages/873.html) explains

> it is a way of saying that the person is 'in touch' and appreciates the actualities of the business rather than being a 'bean-counter' (accountant) a 'paper pusher' (administrator) or a 'fat-cat' (overpaid manager).
>
> obviously the original '**coal-face**' is a mining term to describe an underground worker that actually cuts the coal from the rock - but the sense of direct involvement with the core of the business is the important element, rather than it being dangerous or dirty.

Considering today's high-technology age, I think it sounds old-fashioned and outdated. Is there a more *modern* equivalent?

---

EDIT

From the comments it seems that many American English speakers are unfamiliar with the British idiom. Which AmEng expression or idiom could replace "at the coalface" in the passage quoted above?

Comment: Not quite the question you're asking but possibly "I haven't looked down a microscope" might suit the sentence better.

Comment: Curiously 'at the coalface' usage seems to be on the rise, especially in UK: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=at+the+coalface%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cat+the+coalface%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20coalface%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cat%20the%20coalface%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Maybe *crunching code* ...?

Comment: Maybe it's a reflection on my age, but I've never heard "at the coalface" in AmEng.  Honestly, I assumed that it was something racist from the title (that's American PCness for ya).

Comment: *getting my hands dirty* ...?

Comment: I, also am unfamiliar with this expression - never heard it used in AmE.

Comment: @LittleEva - as shown in the Google NGram above, the expression is used mainly in UK.

Comment: I hear you in general. Just is in the quote you provided, "I haven't dug in in years" seemed to work. I may be wrong! Thanks!

Comment: used in the negative sense, it sounds more plausible but the double "in" is a bit awkward.

Comment: Having never heard the word _coalface_ in any other context than this expression, I was slightly surprised to find it defined by [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/coalface) as “an exposed surface of coal in a mine”. I had always in my mind imagined people _at the coalface_ to be something like stokers on old-fashioned stokers (with unavoidable flashbacks to the _Titanic_ movie), the ‘coalface’ being the mountains of coal being heaved into the furnaces. Just goes to show how much of a city boy I really am, I guess.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - no surprise that a good (tech related) answer is hard to come by. Nowadays we still use idioms whose roots are to be traced in centuries-old trades, jobs, customs which often no longer exist. In a tech-dominated world were more and more people are addicted to digital devices, idioms related to technology are still quite rare compared to the long-established ones. Language moves much slower than technology and that is probably a point you want to make with your question.

Comment: This question is roughly  along the same line:http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225364/paper-never-refused-ink-has-any-one-heard-a-more-modern-online-version/225371#225371

Comment: I've never heard of "at the coalface". Not even once. -BrE x 30yrs

Comment: Given that this expression is still in use, and that coal mining is still a thing in many places, I'm surprised that there are places where the existing idiom isn't understood. Oh, well.

Comment: @user867 Perhaps it is not well-known, quite a few Americans and a couple of Britons have stated to never hearing this expression, which is different from not *understanding* it. Yes, there are still coal mines, but their number is shrinking, along with the number of actual coal miners. Reading the excerpt which undoubtedly deals with modern technology, I thought there had to be a more modern hi-tech version. Seems I was wrong!

Comment: @Mari-LouA For some reason, the traction of idioms has nothing to do with how well they relate to speakers' real life experience. Just like boiling a frog.

Answer (score 35):

Perhaps *[in the trenches](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/In+the+Trenches)*. In the context of medicine (but it can be applied to any field that has active practitioners as well as academics and commentators) it has been defined as

> A popular phrase derived from trench warfare of World War I, referring to the active practice of medicine—in the 'real' world—as opposed to the less practical philosophies of the 'academic' world

*Segen's Medical Dictionary*

But given you request for a more modern idiom, this may be a bit esoteric (and perhaps not understood by generations unfamiliar with World War I).

Comment: +1 Very good - I didn't realize that's where the expression came from.

Comment: I don’t know if I, at 32, would qualify as being from a generation unfamiliar with World War I, but I’ve always associated _in the trenches_ with semi-old-fashioned warfare, when fights were actually fought at relatively close hand, from actual trenches. Esotericity apart, the main problem with this in relation to this particular question is that such warfare doesn’t seem any less outdated or old-fashioned than miners working in coal mines—quite the opposite.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet My grandfather worked *at the coalface* and fought *in the trenches*. While I am more than double your age, my sons and grandchildren will still hear about those toiling in the mines and dying on vicious battlefields. Whether those idioms continue remains to be seen.  This [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+trenches&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20trenches%3B%2Cc0) suggests that, while usage peaked in the 1920s, it has fairly constant usage over the past 80 years.

Comment: The phrases *in the trenches* and also *at the front* or *on the front-lines* (suggested below by @Richard) are all military terms meaning to be in the heart of combat. I believe (but am not sure) that the phrase "in the zone" also originates from the same meaning ("in the combat zone").

Comment: *In the trenches* might not be more up-to-date than *at the coalface* but it does answer the question of what idiom is commonly used in America.

Answer (score 23):

You've got a range of choices;

- I haven't been **on the front-lines**
- I haven't been **hands on**
- I haven't been involved with **the nuts and bolts**
- I haven't been involved **with the nitty-gritty**
- I haven't been involved with **the day-to-day operations** (or even just **"the day-to-day"**).

That said, '*at the coal-face*' would be perfectly acceptable and explicable to most English speakers.

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_the_coal_face) offers some additional alternatives.

Comment: You might also want to consider something more ironic such as "I haven't **slaved away** at a microscope for years" or even "I haven't been doing any **gruntwork/scutwork**" if you don't care about disparaging the lower level staff.

Comment: My first thought was also "hands-on"

Answer (score 16):

I'd go with this:

> I haven't **got/gotten my hands dirty** in years.

Comment: In the medical profession, this would be heavily frowned upon :-)

Comment: @Richard Hahaha. What would an ex surgeon say then? "I haven't got my hands blood-stained in years"?

Comment: For a surgeon? "I haven't been up to my elbows in blood for a while", perhaps?

Answer (score 11):

My great-grandparents were of mining stock, but fortunately I don't have to work underground.
I'm a software developer and often speak about 'working at the code-face'.

Comment: +1 just because this is a brilliant pun, even if it’s not in common use (or possibly even recognisable by most people).

Comment: The code-face is a new one for me, but I consistently mis-hear the song "Working in the Coal Mine" as "...in the Code Mine".

Answer (score 5):

A software development specific example would be:

I haven't **cut code** in years.

Comment: This is closer to what I was hoping for, could one use this phrase if their profession was not a programmer?

Comment: I never heard it in common speech, though "Cutting code" is precisely an IT slang term for "writing code". The term has been around for at least 50 years." http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2042574&langid=14

Comment: @Josh61 It doesn't really matter to me how "old" the expression is, as long as it sounds modern and closer to 21st century than 19th or early 20th century.

Comment: I was not suggesting it is old, but that it has been around for a while. Not enough to entrer common speech IMO :)

Comment: Anecdotal: Cutting code probably refers to a time from either punch card (where you could cut out the holes to produce code) or from paper tape (where you could cut out sections of programs)

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "hands-on" would be the most commonly heard substitute for "at the coalface" that you will find although it has no sense of using advanced technology.  It would be a shame if "at the coalface" dropped completely out of use since it evokes how down and dirty daily labor can be.
I started coding using punched cards in 1976 and I have never heard the expression "cut code" so I'm a little dubious about how common it might be.
Common idioms can be several generations out of date.  The Irish frequently use the word "yoke", as in "yoke the horse to the plow", where an American would likely say "widget" to mean any random piece of machinery.

Answer (score 0):

In tech-related fields you could say, you are working or dealing with **cutting-edge** or **bleeding-edge** stuff. This, however, describes more your work, rather than the way you are working.

Comment: Also - *at the sharp end*.

Answer (score 0):

How about "**worked the streets**" which contrary to public opinion is not about prostitutes but rather mongers, hawkers, and other street vendors. Police also adopt the term sometimes.

Comment: I've *only* heard that term used by police. I'd certainly use it if a police officer got moved to desk / management work, but I don't think it really generalizes.

Answer (score 0):

To me the modern software development equivalent is: "I haven't fired up a compiler in a while" meaning I haven't written any code lately.