# Synonym for "from the trenches"

Tags: expressions, synonyms, phrase-requests

The expression "from the trenches" implies a down-to-reality focus as in "a view from the trenches".

Is there any other english expression implying the same meaning ?

Comment: "From the coalface" ?

Comment: [*On the ground*](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/on+the+ground.html) as opposed to *in the clouds*, *from the ivory tower*, or using a *40,000 foot view*.

Comment: from the coalface is excellent IMHO - @Chenmunka would you mind putting it as answer ?

Comment: almost a duplicate: [A modern equivalent for “at the coalface”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/225564/a-modern-equivalent-for-at-the-coalface)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'll go so far as to say it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a reference to coal mining:  *A view from the coalface*.
Working at the coalface is the hottest, dirtiest and hardest work in a coal mine.  The expression emphasizes that situation.

It is being used in current debates, for example this one from Cambridge University: [*What Brexit means for UK science: a view from the coalface*](http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/discussion/opinion-what-brexit-means-for-uk-science-a-view-from-the-coalface) and other [academic sources](http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/1309952/).

Answer (score 1):

“Word on the street” refers to ordinary people. However it does relate specifically to what they think or believe.